# How to update pie chart using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have two different data sets and I am trying to create pie charts with the first set and then listen for an event and transition to the second set.

I can successfully create the pie charts from the first set of data using this code

```
var data = [[70, 30],[60, 40],[50, 50],[95, 5],[87, 13]];

progress.pie.vars.svg = d3.select( progress.pie.vars.pieEl ).selectAll("svg")
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 150)
            .attr("height", 150)
          .each(function(d) { this.currentAngles = d; }); // store the initial angles;

progress.pie.vars.path = progress.pie.vars.svg.selectAll("path")
          .data(function(d, i){ return pie(d) })
          .enter().append("path")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + 75 + ", " + 75 + ")")
            .attr("d", arc);
```

Note: *I am using hardcoded data here, I can replicate using JSON but I wanted to simplify things just so I can get the transitions working.*

This creates the svg's and renders them on the page but the problem occurs when I use the other data set and try to update the paths. Like this...

```
var data = [[60, 40], [10, 10, 10, 70], [30, 70], [25, 25, 25, 25], [30, 35, 35]];

progress.pie.vars.svg = progress.pie.vars.svg.selectAll("svg")
          .data(data);

progress.pie.vars.path = progress.pie.vars.path
          .data(function(d, i){ return pie(d) })
          .enter().append("path")
            .transition()
            .duration(5000);
```

I have researched the d3 general update pattern but I don't quite understand it yet.

If anyone has any suggestions how to solve my problem or improve my code then its much appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `progress.pie.vars.svg` contains the newly appended  elements, you don't need to `selectAll("svg")`.  That would be selecting for any `svg` elements under your `svg` elements. You should be able to just call `data` directly on the selection you have.

For the `progress.pie.vars.path` data bind, it looks like you're only handling the enter case for adding new paths (although you're not assigning a `d` path attribute as you did with the original pies). You'll want to add new arcs for new data and update the arcs for updated data.  You can do this by keeping the update selection separate from the enter selection:

```
progress.pie.vars.path = progress.pie.vars.path
    .data(function(d, i){ return pie(d) });

progress.pie.vars.path.enter().append("path");

progress.pie.vars.path.attr("d", arc);
```

New nodes added to the enter selection are implicitly added to the update selection so that last line will be operating on both the new and existings.  (Note this doesn't handle exit).

You should check out Mike Bostock's excellent tutorial [Thinking With Joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it cleared up a few things. everything is working now except each time the code would redraw all the paths. I want to enhance it to do something like this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5681842. Could I paste some more code here for you to look at? The only problem I'm having is that the pie charts don't transition for some reason.

Comment: Not sure if it's your current problem, but you'll need a custom tween to interpolate the arc angle nicely.  Check out arcTween() in the example you link to.

Comment: The arc does interpolate properly but it just doesn't transition. Here I am storing angles , taken from the example I linked to.  


    `.attrTween("d", progress.pie.tweenPie)`
    `.each(function(d) { this._current = d; });`

Comment: And here is my version of arcTween  
  `tweenPie: function(b) {
      var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                  .innerRadius(progress.pie.vars.innerRadius)
                  .outerRadius(progress.pie.vars.outerRadius);
        b.innerRadius = 0;
         var i = d3.interpolate(this._current,  b);
         this._current = i(0);
         return function(t) {
           return arc(i(t));
      };
    }`

Comment: Hmm, if your attrTween() comes after the transition() in the call chain it should do its thing. Can you link to a bl.ocks or jsFiddle where the final code lives?

Comment: here's a link to the gist https://gist.github.com/ConnorAtherton/6163960, I'm trying to get it to work on bl.ocks but no luck so far

Comment: got it http://bl.ocks.org/ConnorAtherton/6164066 :) Thanks for helping me out Scott

Comment: On line 141 of progress.js you set this._current in an .each function.  transition.each will run right away but pieTween is scheduled to run asynchronously on the next animation frame.  By the time pieTween actually runs, this._current has already been set to the new data so b === this._current meaning your interpolator is interpolating from/to the same value. You can set up a default value for _current if you want or just have the tween handle the missing property gracefully.  But other than that, only the tween should touch _current so you don't get burned by asynchronous invocation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34926/discussion-between-connor-atherton-and-scott-cameron)